# javascript two windows to compare content?

Tags: javascript, iframe

im new to JS but have done some basic posts. In this case the user presses a button and a post happens to a server that generates a bunch of json data and sends it back. I want to take this JSON data and populate a nice looking page to display it on the left "window". I'll use the term window but its probably not correct. This I can figure out.

But then lets say I wanted to show a similar layout on the right "window" but with updated json data. This way the user can then compare the two side by side.

I've searched for frames but it seems those are to only load existing webpages? Should I be dynamically creating new webpages and then populating the frames with the sites I create?

Ironically the layout I see at

```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_get
```

is pretty much what I want. Content on the left, content on the right with a separation in the middle. (not the actual example linked).

Some general guidance on which way to go where would be helpful. Thx!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Just have two divs using flex for layout and pre for content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to create two divs, side by side, and style them with css to make it look nice. Inside each div create a `pre` tag and put your json data in them formatted using JSON.stringify. The `pre` tag tells the browser that the content is pre formatted and it can be used 'as-is'

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hv8dyxzc/1/

```js
var dataLeft = {
    "code": 50,
    "data": {
        "list": [
            {
                "id": "10",
                "date": "2021-02-03",
                "status": "3"
            },
            {
                "id": "20",
                "date": "2021-01-26",
                "status": "0"
            },
        ],
        "startDate": "2021-02-20",
        "totalPages": 2
    }
}

var dataRight = {
    "code": 50,
    "data": {
        "list": [
            {
                "id": "10",
                "date": "2021-02-04",
                "status": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": "20",
                "date": "2021-01-26",
                "status": "0"
            },
        ],
        "startDate": "2021-02-20",
        "totalPages": 2
    }
}


document.getElementById("json-left").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dataLeft, undefined, 4);
document.getElementById("json-right").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(dataRight, undefined, 4);
```

```css
.main-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 1em;
}

.window {
  width: 45%;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #BBB);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="window">
    <pre id="json-left"></pre>
  </div>
  <div class="window">
    <pre id="json-right"></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very pretty. Above and beyond

Comment: thank you! this is the perfect example for me to start with. really appreciate it.